# Why does this input button appear correctly centered in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox?

Tags: html, css

Why does this input button appear correctly centered in Chrome but in IE or Firefox appears to the right. Here is the link, it is the second button on the right side:

Site : http://dallaspetsalive.org/about/

HTML :

```
<div style="float:center;text-align:center;">
<form action="http://linkhidden" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email     address" required>
<br /><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"    class="button" style="text-align:center;float:center;" >
</form>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
input.button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E8E8E8 0%, #D1D1D1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #F5F5F5 inset;
    color: #656464;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
}
```

Comment: I think float: center doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `float: center` doesn't exist. Change the inline style and add the following:

```
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
```

---

Your input tag shall be

```
<input 
    type="submit" 
    value="Subscribe" 
    name="subscribe" 
    id="mc-embedded-subscribe"
    class="button" 
    style="float:none; margin: 0 auto;" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button has a selector on CSS 'input.button' that has float:right.
This is the code I found with firebug:

```
input.button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E8E8E8 0%, #D1D1D1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #F5F5F5 inset;
    color: #656464;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
}
```

If you remove float right it centers on firefox, I guess chrome and explorer as well.
Or in HTML:

```
<div style="float:none; text-align:center;">
```

Comment: Thanks. I found where that was happening in my CSS. I thought the style I put in the html would override it but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @ktbird7 Yes, the inline style does override it.

Comment: Good, to override it in HTML you need to say style="float:none"